# Two different shell envrionments for Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci

The situation is that my tests are HTTP calls based, so when I am testing in my local environment, I run server in one shell, and then run my tests in a different shell.

Is it possible to make this is happen in travis-ci. If not, what is the work around, otherwise my build is always going to fail.

Following is my `.travis.yml` file

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "7.10.0"
services:
 - mongodb
env:
 - PORT=6655 IP="localhost" NODE_ENV="test"
before_script: 
 - npm start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always start a process in the background. Try it like this:

```
script:
- run_server & # runs server in background
- sleep .3     # gives server .3 seconds to start up, if needed
- query_server # your http query commands
```

Of course change to your needs.

Comment: Hey, could you explain this a bit more, or refer to a document or something? So, I added 

`script:
 - npm start &
`
, but I got build passed and none of the tests ran.

Comment: I made slight changes to the yml file
`script: - npm start & - sleep 5` but my tests run before the server starts, now all tests are failing

Comment: Okay, I fixed it by increasing the value of sleep. Thanks for you help